# Is Music Production covered here?

Tags: discussion

Hey I am new to this site and would like to know if Music Production covered here?

I know that a proposal for one is going on [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100727/music-production/106296#106296) but does this SE cover it right now?

Comment: On top of what Dave  and topo said, if you ask a question here which is sort of on the edge, and it gets no useful answers, it is very easy to migrate it over to Sound Design (I'm a mod on both sites :-) )

Comment: Tip o' the hat for asking on meta before asking on the main site. And a very warm welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

(almost?) All questions about *music* production should be on topic here, tracking, mixing mastering etc.  the main boundary I could see running into is generic audio manipulation, such as as  for voice overs or sound effects, that wouldn't typically be on topic here.  These tend to fit better at [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40670/noise-in-usb-audio-interface) and it might be the case that for some types of questions, they have better expertise in the relevant.

Comment: Did you mean to link to a particular question on Sound Design instead of to the site's front page?

Comment: No, just to to provide a convenient link for any readers who are not familiar with Sound Design.

Answer (score 4):

To echo Dave - Yes!

They were seen as fine a couple of years ago: **[Are Questions on Production, mixing and mastering allowed on the site?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/are-questions-on-production-mixing-and-mastering-allowed-on-the-site)** ... and things haven't changed on this point since then, as far as I can see.

It seems to me that most of the questions on the current Music Production proposal would fit here, and those that wouldn't would (as Dave says) fit on [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/).

It is true that we don't always get the most active response to some detailed questions about how to use particular pieces of software. But if there's a group of people with expertise in this area who want an SE community, them coming here would solve that!